# TSQL - Case statement + Concatenate 2 columns + select 10 characters from right in one

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, concatenation, case

I'm trying to concatenate two fields in a case statement, where I only want the 10 characters from the right for the second field.  The first field is a 25-character varchar field (twfcompID); the second field is a text field (t.TransNotes).  I want to end up with something that looks like 497-2059--281369.pdf.   Here is my syntax that isn't working.

```
(Case
    WHEN l.TWFCompID = 'FCLMIL' THEN    
        CAST(m.MatterID AS VARCHAR(100)) + '--' + 
        RIGHT(CAST(t.TransNotes,10) AS VARCHAR(100))
    WHEN l.TWFCompID like 'f-%' THEN
        CAST(m.MatterID AS VARCHAR(100)) + '--' + (right(t.TransNotes,10) AS VARCHAR(100)) 
    WHEN l.TWFCompID like 'FS-%' THEN
        CAST(m.MatterID AS VARCHAR(100)) + '--' + CAST(right(t.TransNotes,10) AS VARCHAR(100)) 
ELSE '' END) AS 'LineItemID',
```

---

When I run this, I get the error:
Msg 1035, Level 15, State 10, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the first `WHEN` clause.  The parameters for the `RIGHT` and the `CAST` are mixed up.  Try this.

```
WHEN l.TWFCompID = 'FCLMIL' THEN    
    CAST(m.MatterID AS VARCHAR(100)) + '--' + 
    CAST(RIGHT(t.TransNotes, 10) AS VARCHAR(100))
```

an alternative is to use the following, which switches the `CAST` and `RIGHT` statements

```
WHEN l.TWFCompID = 'FCLMIL' THEN    
    CAST(m.MatterID AS VARCHAR(100)) + '--' + 
    RIGHT(CAST(t.TransNotes AS VARCHAR(100)), 10)
```

You may also be missing the `CAST` keyword in the second `WHEN` clause.

Comment: I had it that way first but in that case I get the error: Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of right function.  However you were right about the second cast. I've rewritten it 100 times.  The transNotes field is that unlimited text field.

Comment: Thanks:  Still struggling. 
It looks like you can't use the **RIGHT** keyword on a field that is a text field.  What function can you use to get only the **last 10 characters** of whatever is in the field?
**When I use the syntax as you suggest, I get** 
> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Argument data type text is invalid
> for argument 1 of right function.

Comment: I edited my answer to include an alternative.  It switches the position of the RIGHT and CAST functions, so that the data type is changed first and then the RIGHT function is applied.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked.  I also had gotten this from a friend and it also works: **+ CAST (RIGHT(CAST(t.TransNotes AS VARCHAR(max)),11) as varchar(25))**